# Java Regex String Matching

Tags: java, regex

I am using the Regex matcher for approximate string matching. I have a question regarding how to make it allow for overlapping matches. Currently, it finds a match then skips to the end of that hit and searches starting there.

Current Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class BNDM2 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nucleotides,pattern;
    System.out.print("Enter sequence:");
    pattern = sc.nextLine(); 
    System.out.print("Enter nucleotides:");
    nucleotides= sc.nextLine(); 

    // first convert the pattern into a proper regex
    // i.e. replacing any N with [ATCG]
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern.replaceAll("N", "[ATCG]"));

    // create a Matcher to find everywhere that the pattern matches
    Matcher m = regex.matcher(nucleotides);

    // find all the matches
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Match found:");
        System.out.println("start:" + m.start());
        System.out.println("end:" + (m.end() - 1)); // minus 1 here because the end of a regex match is always off by 1
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("|" + nucleotides.substring(m.start(),m.end())+"|......");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your input data, the results you're getting, and the how they differ from your expected results?

Comment: You're probably going to need quantifiers but as mypetlion says, hard to help you without input + current output vs desired output...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `public boolean find(int start)` and loop through your entire String

```
 int index = 0;

 while (index < nucleotides.length()  && m.find(index)) {
          //your code here
          index=m.start()+1;
 }
```